# How to reduce distance between two line of Vert?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, delimiters

How can I reduce distance between two line of `\Vert`? i.e. I want to have the following `\Vert` (for norm)

[image]

instead of the usual one

[image]

? I remember that the output of `\Vert` in my previous TeXlive (2014) was  thinner than these two. (maybe I am wrong).

```
\documentclass[12pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand{\Norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\begin{document}
    \[\Norm{df}^2 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a full compileable code.

Comment: @AndréC: I don't know the code of first one obviously!!

Comment: In order to be growable, the double bars are built from a couple of glyphs in the math font, so the other example may be using a different math symbol font (and in fact the other glyphs d, f, 2 look different as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For use with the standard fonts (Latin Modern or Computer Modern), you can use the version of `\Vert` in `mathabx`, which is indeed thinner, without loading the whole package.

Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, etoolbox}
\usepackage[b]{esvect} 

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
<-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8> matha7
<8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9
<10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\vvvert} {0}{matha}{"7E}{mathx}{"17}%
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\xVert} {0}{matha}{"7D}{mathx}{"0F}%

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\norm}[1]{\Vert}{\Vert} {\ifblank{#1}{\: · \:}{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\abxnorm}[1]{\xVert}{\xVert} {\ifblank{#1}{\: · \:}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[ \norm{\vv{u}_{\!i}} \]
\[ \abxnorm*{\vv{u}_{\!i}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`\Vert` uses a single character, (‖) not two drawn lines, so the question is the same as asking to change the width of H, with the same answer, you need to choose a different font.

Looking at the superscript 2 in your two images, it is clear that different font sets were used with the second image having a distinct bowl at the top of the 2, I'm sure someone will be able to identify the two fonts by eye, but more generally just pick a font that you like.

Comment: So, Is it possible to define (‖ ‖) as `\newcommand{\myvert}{\left\vert\!\left\vert #1 \right\vert\!\right\vert}` ?

Comment: Not really, well you can of course but normally it's best to avoid `\left\right` and use  fixed sizes, and so you would have to make a command at each size, also it depends whether search and plain text cut and paste matters and you want it to be the correct symbol internally @C.F.G

Answer (score 1):

The upper screenshot in your posting employs a Times Roman clone, whereas the lower screenshot employs either Computer Modern or Latin Modern. As I'm sure you know, apples-to-oranges comparisons are frequently problematic.

Here are some screenshots meant to let viewers compare the appearance of the "norm" double vertical bars across five font choices. The first row employs Computer Modern; the next four rows employ various Times Roman clones. In all cases, the image on the left is for inline math and the one on the right for display-style math; as is easily verified, the difference between the two math modes is in the vertical position of the exponent term. (Aside: In order to make the visual comparisons straightforward, I've employed the same magnification scale across all five screenshots.)

Computer Modern [image]

---

NewTX Math [image]

---

MathTime II Professional [image]

---

Stix Two Math [image]

---

XITS Math [image]

---

To my eye, the main difference across math font choices is not the distance between the vertical bars. Instead, it is the *thickness* of the vertical bars. A second, maybe somewhat less readily apparent difference is in the *height* of the vertical bars; Computer Modern's vertical bars are quite a bit taller than those of the four Times Roman candidates. That said, of the four Times Roman candidates examined above, I'd say that the `MathTime Professional II` font features the narrowest spacing between the pairs of vertical bars.

What's the upshot? If you simply *must* employ a font that features somewhat narrowly spaced vertical bars, and if you're ok with a Times Roman font, you may want to give the MathTime Professional II fonts a try. Warning: The full `mtpro2` package is not free of charge; however, its `lite` subset, which is all that's required to use `\Vert`, is in fact free.

---

Finally, here's the code I used to generate the screenshots shown above.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  %\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
  \setmainfont{XITS}\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\else
  %\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
  \usepackage{newtxtext,mtpro2}
\fi

\begin{document}
$\norm{df}^2\quad\displaystyle\norm{df}^2$
\end{document}
```